# Pjsip compile error in iphone-simulator not able to setup in ios 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, pjsip, siphon

I am trying to compile pjsip source code for iphone.

My problem is when i compile this code for simulator  ./configure- 
iphone   works fine and i get 
Done configuring for iPhoneOS7.1.sdk.

but when i run make dep command i get error

echo '../bin/pjlib-test-arm-apple-darwin9: ../lib/libpj-arm-apple-darwin9.a' >> .pjlib-test-arm-apple-darwin9.depend
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f /Users/SureshBK/desktop/pjproject/build/rules.mak APP=PJLIB_UTIL app=pjlib-util depend
.pjlib-util-arm-apple-darwin9.depend:709: *** missing separator.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [depend] Error 2
make: *** [dep] Error 1.

Please help me how to solve this error. 
i am using mac 10.9
and iPhone sdk 7.1

thankyou

Comment: Can any one help to setup Pjsip for ios....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never used PjSip in my apps. But i can suggest you to checkout the following links, may be helps you.
All the best.

https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/iPhone

http://blog.pjsip.org/2014/09/04/pjsip-version-2-3-is-released-with-video-on-ios/